# How can I train my own Chinese NER model

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to train my own Chinese NER model by https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html mentioned. I converted the data to one Chinese character per line, and labeled entities after character, it likes:

---

> 红 ORG
>
> 帽 ORG
>
> 首 O
>
> 席 O
>
> 执 O
>
> 行 O
>
> 官 O
>
> Jim PERSON
>
> Whitehurst PERSON
>
> 曾 O
>
> 表 O
>
> 示 O
>
> ， O
>
> 亚 ORG
>
> 马 ORG
>
> 逊 ORG
>
> 公 O
>
> 共 O
>
> 云 O
>
> 有 O
>
> 许 O
>
> 多 O

### ...

After using command `java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop tech.prop`, it finally generated the classfier(chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz). Then I checked the classfier how it works on annotated test data, I used command `java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz -testFile test.tsv`, it seems to work.

But when I checked the classifier by a text paragraph instead of annotated test data using command`java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textfile test.txt`, it seems that the classifier is useless, it didn't recognize the word-segmented Chinese.

---

Is there any problem when I trained new Chinese NER model?
One probably problem I think is that I convert training data to one Chinese character per line. In fact in Chinese one Chinese character not a Chinese word, should I use word-segmented Chinese training data and convert the data to one Chinese word per line, then label the Chinese word instead of Chinese character.

Answer (score 0):

Flags that may be useful for handling different types of text input are:

```
-plainTextDocumentReaderAndWriter CLASSNAME Specify a class to read text documents (which extends DocumentReaderAndWriter)
-tokenizerFactory CLASSNAME Specify a class to do tokenization (which extends TokenizerFactory)
-tokenizerOptions "tokenizeNLs=true,asciiQuotes=true" Give options to the tokenizer, such as the two example options here.
```

This might be useful too:
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html

Apart from these, you should take a look at Chinese word-segmenter features in SeqClassifierFlags.